# how to run Redmine with docker-compose in development environment

Tags: docker-compose, redmine

I use redmine docker official image. I run redmine via docker-compose. My docker-compose.yml is :

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  redmine:
    image: redmine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:3000
    volumes:
      - ./storage/docker_redmine-plugins:/usr/src/redmine/plugins
      - ./storage/docker_redmine-themes:/usr/src/redmine/public/themes
      - ./storage/docker_redmine-data:/usr/src/redmine/files
    environment:
      REDMINE_DB_MYSQL: db
      REDMINE_DB_PASSWORD: example
      REDMINE_SECRET_KEY_BASE: supersecretkey
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_DATABASE: redmine
```

This configuration runs successfully with the command `docker-compose up`. Redmine start on production environment. But how start Redmine in development environment. I saw available environment variables on official image Redmine page but not see environment for rails server. Is there a way to run Redmine in development environment by adding instruction to docker-compose.yml ?